# Singleton Factory to produces multiple singleton instances

Tags: c#, singleton

I have two singleton classes in my project.

```
public class VStateManager : IVState
{
    private static readonly object _createLock = new object();
    private static VStateManager _vsManager = null;
    public static VStateManager GetVStateManager()
    {
        lock (_createLock)
        {
            if (_vsManager == null)
            {
                return new VStateManager();
            }
            return _vsManager;
        }
    }
}

public class VTRFactory : IVTR
{
    private static VehicleFactory _VTRFactory =null;
    private static readonly object _createLock = new object();

    public static VehicleFactory GetVTRFactory()
    {
        lock(_createLock)
        {
            if(_VTRFactory == null)
            {
                return new VTRFactory();
            }
            return _VTRFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

My colleague suggested to create a singleton class (`something like a singleton factory`) that accepts a generic interface and produces both these `singleton objects`

How can this be done.?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your classes aren't implementing singleton at all. Look at this:

```
if (_vsManager == null)
{
   return new VStateManager();
}
return _vsManager;
```

`_vsManager` will be always null, so multiple instances will be created each time you access the instance. It should be:

```
if (_vsManager == null)
{
   _vsManager = new VStateManager();
}
return _vsManager;
```

That's the way you ensure only one instance will be created.

Also, I would use a property instead of a function, it's more clear:

```
public class VStateManager : IVState
{
    private static readonly object _createLock = new object();
    private static VStateManager _vsManager = null;
    public static VStateManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_createLock)
            {
                if (_vsManager == null)
                {
                    _vsManager = new VStateManager();
                }
                return _vsManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use per example `VStateManager.Instance.XXX`.

Second, why you need a third class to create those singletons? When you need to use them accessing `GetXXXX` would create the needed instance, is there any reason to create those instances before you need them?

If you really need those instances to be initialized before they are needed then you can do something very simple like this:

```
public static class Initializer()
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        var a = VStateManager.GetVStateManager();
        var b = VehicleFactory.GetVTRFactory();
    }
}
```

Then to initialize just call `Initializer.Init()`.  Overcomplicating the code without any reason is the root of all evil in programming, don't try to solve a problem that doesn't exists as that solution can create real problems.

Answer (score 2):

The singleton factory you are looking for can be created using generics. You need to pass the type for which you need to create a singleton instance and the factory will return an instance of that type with making sure that only one instance of that type is created.

The very basic implementation of such singleton factory would look as following.

```
public static class SingletonFactory
{
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
    //Dictionary to store the singleton objects 
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> singletonObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    // Method to retrieve singleton instance.
    // Note the constraint "new ()". This indicates that this method can be called for the types which has default constructor.
    public static T GetSingletoneInstance<T>() where T:new ()
    {
        var typeName = typeof(T).Name;
        T instance;

        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // Check in the dictionary if the instance already exist.
            if (singletonObjects.ContainsKey(typeName))
            {
                //Retrieve the instance from the dictionary.
                instance = (T) singletonObjects[typeName];
            }
            else
            {
                // If it does not exist in the dictionary, 
                // create a new instance 
                // and store it in the dictionary.
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    instance = new T();

                    singletonObjects.Add(typeName, instance);
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the instance of type "T" either retrieved from dictionary 
        // or the newly created one.
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Following is how you use this factory.

```
class Program
{

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vstateManager = SingletonFactory.GetSingletoneInstance<VStateManager>();

        var vehicleFactory = SingletonFactory.GetSingletoneInstance<VehicleFactory>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The implementation of SingletonFactory is a very basic version. And it has limitation that it can be used only for the types which have default constructor.

But it can be further extended to use DI module to initialize the instances without worrying about their constructors. Also it can be extended to store the instances in somewhere else then dictionary such as cache, memcaches or database.

I hope this would help you get whatever you are looking for.